# Exact match from list of words from a text in R

Tags: r, regex

I have list of words and I am looking for words that are there in the text. 
The result is that in the last column is always found as it is searching for patterns. I am looking for exact match that is there in words. Not the combinations. For the first three records it should be not found. 
Please guide where I am going wrong.

```
col_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
col_2 <- c("work instruction change", 
           "technology npi inspections", 
           " functional locations",
           "Construction has started",
           " there is going to be constn coon")


df <- as.data.frame(cbind(col_1,col_2))
df$col_2 <- tolower(df$col_2)
words <- c("const","constn","constrction","construc",
                    "construct","construction","constructs","consttntype","constypes","ct","ct#",
                    "ct2"
                    )


pattern_words  <- paste(words, collapse = "|")
df$result<- ifelse(str_detect(df$col_2, regex(pattern_words)),"Found","Not Found")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use word boundaries around the `words`.

```
library(stringr)

pattern_words  <- paste0('\\b', words, '\\b', collapse = "|")
df$result <- c('Not Found', 'Found')[str_detect(df$col_2, pattern_words) + 1]
#OR with `ifelse`
#df$result <- ifelse(str_detect(df$col_2, pattern_words), "Found", "Not Found")

df
#  col_1                             col_2    result
#1     1           work instruction change Not Found
#2     2        technology npi inspections Not Found
#3     3              functional locations Not Found
#4     4          construction has started     Found
#5     5  there is going to be constn coon     Found
```

You can also use `grepl` here to keep it in base R :

```
grepl(pattern_words, df$col_2)
```